# Using Tailscale to route traffic from a proxy VPS to my homelab results in incredibly slow speeds

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, tailscale

I have a VPS that I am using as a reverse proxy to forward traffic to my personal server at home. The two servers are connected by Tailscale, and the VPS is running Nginx, which takes some subdomains, and proxies them to my homelab's Tailscale IP. The issue is that the download speed from my homelab is incredibly slow (~400 KB/s), whereas when I connect to it plainly through Tailscale, the speed is about 15-20 MB/s. The upload speed is entirely unaffected.

What I've tried:

- Playing with my Nginx config
- More powerful VPS
- Different VPS provider
- Using Caddy instead of Nginx

Any possible help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the link between your VPS and your home lab is using a relay? Dunno if you can check that with Tailscale.

Comment: If the communication goes through [DERP Servers](https://tailscale.com/kb/1232/derp-servers/) this slows it down. Tailscale itself is pretty slow ([link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Tailscale/comments/z455o3/vpn_speeds_way_slower_than_they_should_be/)). Try [ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com/) instead.

Comment: Yes, on the admin panel it shows that my homelab is using a relay